# Installing a group of .deb files

Tags: package-management

I have a directory of .deb files which I copied from the cache folder of apt. There are many applications and Ubuntu updates among them. but there's no dependency failure because they were all downloaded by 'add/remove applications' and 'update manager' automatically.

Now I have installed the same version of Ubuntu (9.04) and I want to install those apps and updates again(though they are not new versions). In other words, I want to make this fresh Ubuntu install exactly like the old one but without downloading any thing and using only those .deb files that I copied. All I have is an archive folder containing the .deb files and a 'pkgcache.bin' file.

I know I can double-click the .deb files and install them manually but then I have to find out and follow the dependencies one by one from the installer errors. 
I have also tried adding an offline repository but it didn't work. I think because all of my .deb's are in on folder, and there is no separate 'main', 'restricted', ... folder?!

Is there a way to do all of this automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eureka!

All I had to do to install a group of .deb files automatically was:

1. `cd deb-files-location`
2. `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Comment: beat me to it :P Correct if wrong but the new USC also does it when you open loads of .deb files at a time?